# Using ethereumj to evaluate contracts off chain

Tags: ethereumj

Is it possible to take a contract from the main ethereum blockchain and used that on my private ethereum network with ethereumj?

What I want to do is, run a contract with some input without changing the blockchain and spending gas.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethereumj provides a class called *[StandAloneBlockchain.java](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/165fe6060ca40325debcc3356b02c634f1f945ee/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/util/blockchain/StandaloneBlockchain.java)*. You can see it in use [here](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/165fe6060ca40325debcc3356b02c634f1f945ee/ethereumj-core/src/test/java/org/ethereum/util/StandaloneBlockchainTest.java).

```
StandaloneBlockchain sb = new StandaloneBlockchain().withAutoblock(true);
SolidityContract a = sb.submitNewContract(
                "contract A {" +
                    "  uint public a;" +
                    "  uint public b;" +
                    "  function A(uint a_, uint b_) {a = a_; b = b_; }" +
                       "}",
                    "A", 555, 777
);
```

With this you'll be able to test for expected results without actually using any real ETH/gas. Therefore you'll have an idea of how the real transaction may behave on the network.

You can do this by inspecting the balance before and after the transaction is executed. The [code](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/165fe6060ca40325debcc3356b02c634f1f945ee/ethereumj-core/src/test/java/org/ethereum/util/StandaloneBlockchainTest.java) below asserts that an amount was sent; However you can conduct a more detailed inspection of the account balances to get an idea for how much the transaction cost.

```
BigInteger aliceInitBal = sb.getBlockchain().getRepository().getBalance(alice.getAddress());
BigInteger bobInitBal = sb.getBlockchain().getRepository().getBalance(bob.getAddress());
assert convert(123, ETHER).equals(bobInitBal);

sb.setSender(bob);
sb.sendEther(alice.getAddress(), BigInteger.ONE);

sb.createBlock();

assert convert(123, ETHER).compareTo(sb.getBlockchain().getRepository().getBalance(bob.getAddress())) > 0;
assert aliceInitBal.add(BigInteger.ONE).equals(sb.getBlockchain().getRepository().getBalance(alice.getAddress()));
```

The *StandAloneBlockchain.java* class is also useful for unit testing your Solidity contract.

Leave a comment if you need any clarification.

Comment: thanks very much for the quick reply. How do I validate that this code does not use any real ETH/gas?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You'll get an idea of how it works by looking at some of the preexisting code for the StandaloneBlockchain.java tests.

Comment: Thanks @Malone for the reply. I have inspected the balance before and after the transaction but it is failing at `assert convert(123, ETHER).equals(bobInitBal);` when I added the smart contract but works fine without the smart contract.

Comment: If you set the sender before making the call to the smart contract. Then the transaction will be made from that account. Allowing you to check the balance of that account after. Refer to the SolidityContract class to look at how you can interact with the contract. e.g. SolidityCallResult callFunction(String functionName, Object ... args); method. Checkout code that I've wrote relating to this: https://github.com/blmalone/Blockchain-Academic-Verification-Service/blob/master/app/main-blockchain/src/test/java/com/unilog/blockchain/SmartContractTest.java

Comment: ps. this is a separate blockchain the emulates what things would look like in the actual environment.Therefore the ETH spent on this chain is not mirror on the main net. Therefore, you are not spending 'real' ETH so to speak

Comment: Just to be clear. You can use contracts from the Ethereum main net on a private network using Ethereumj. The StandaloneBlockchain is just a quick/light way of emulating the blockchain locally. You can run an ethereum client on the JVM to create a private blockchain and have it mine blocks containing contract code from the main net. You'll not be using 'real' ETH because it's not the same blockchain as the main net i.e. differing genesis blocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68327/discussion-between-berrytchaks-and-malone).